# Pulling photo and photo id from a SQL table and displaying them in a list on a PHP page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, arrays

I have a SQL table which contains ID, photourl and thumbnailurl. Now I've written a script which deletes the photos. Everything is working properly the thing is I want to display the images in a list:

[image: like this]

As you can see, I want to put the photo and the delete link into one list item.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="#"/></li>
            <li><a href="#"> DELETE IMAGE </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="#"/></li>
            <li><a href="#"> DELETE IMAGE </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wrote some code but it doesn't seem to work... it displays the photo's vertically in a list.

```
<ul >
<li>
<?php
    while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject()) {
        //echo '<li>';
            echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li> <img class="thumb_image '.$line->category.'" src="'.$line->minurl.'"/> </li>';
                echo '<li>  <a href="index.php?remove=true&id='.$line->id.'">Verwijder</a> </li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        //echo '</li>';
        /*echo '<img class="thumb_image '.$line->category.'" src="'.$line->minurl.'"/> <br/> <a href="index.php?remove=true">Verwijder</a> ';
    */
    }

    
?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is a css and html problem.

Comment: @KrisTemmerman - If you are seeking an HTML/CSS solution, please post all the relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting your HTML up like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="#"/><a href="#" class="deleteImage"> DELETE IMAGE </a></li>
 </ul>
```

and then your CSS as follows:

```
.deleteImage { display: block; }​
```

this will allow you to manipulate where you would like the delete image text to display under the image.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this... use `<table>` and `<li>`
this will give you rough idea.. try something like..

```
<table>
  <ul>
    <tr>
      <td><li> row1 - column1 (1,1) </li></td>
      <td><li> row1 - column2 (1,2) </li></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><li> row2 - column1 (2,1) </li></td>
      <td><li> row2 - column2 (2,2) </li></td>
    </tr>
  </ul>
</table>
```

rest you can figure out yourself..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, what you need is a table, but it doesn't have to look like one:

CSS:

```
table {
    display: block;
}

tr {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 1em;
}

td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52yTm/

You can add extra columns, such as who uploaded it or when the picture was taken, etc. and style those however makes sense.

A list of lists doesn't seem appropriate to me.  A list, in my mind, should be similar things (a grocery list, a list of colors, etc.).  An image and a delete button are dissimilar items with a relationship ("delete" deletes the associated image).  Relationships are better expressed with a table.

Comment: this is a bit more extensive then what i was looking for but this works too !